# Choosing a number puzzle.

Tags: puzzle

A and B play a game, where A begins the game. A can start the game by calling a number from 1 to 10, then the game continues by the other person choosing a number. But rule of game is if one picks x, then the other person can only pick integer between [x+1,x+10]. This means if first time A picks 1, B can pick at most 11 and at least 2.

The first person to call 100 wins the game.

My question is what number should A pick in the first trial so that his winning is guaranteed. This was an interview question.

Comment: When does someone win?

Comment: @Michael Was wondering the same thing

Comment: @Michael Sorry, made the edits.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Where is the explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is one.  Because then whatever $B$ picks $A$ can get to 12, then whatever $B$ picks $A$ can get to 23, then whatever $B$ picks $A$ can get to 34, and then whatever $B$ picks $A$ can get to 45, then whatever $B$ picks $A$ can get  to 56, then whatever $B$ picks $A$ can get to 67, then whatever $B$ picks $A$ can get to 78, then whatever $B$ picks $A$ can get to 89, then whatever $B$ picks $A$ can get to 100